# Excel-VBA loop ifs

Tags: vba, excel

I've written 2 macros to do this task but I'm trying to consolidate and make it more efficient.

- If there is a value = 1 in column `I` (it will either be blank or = 1) then look at column `G`
- If the Value in column `G` < 30  OR  if the Value in column `H` < 0.03 THEN
  overwrite the value in column I to = "0" ... (if not then don't change the value in column `I` and move on to check the next)

The Ranges are `I9:I45000`, `G9:G45000`, and `H9:H45000`.

I think there is a simple solution but after a few hours my un-educated self can't find it.

**Module1:**

```
Dim rngCell As Range, _
    rngDataRange As Range

Set rngDataRange = Range("G9:G45000")
For Each rngCell In rngDataRange
    With rngCell
        If .Value < 30 Then
            .Offset(0, 2).Value = "0"    'A[rngCell] to C[rngCell]
        End If
    End With
Next rngCell
End Sub
```

**Module2:**

```
Sub Macro1()
Dim rngCell As Range, _
    rngDataRange As Range

Set rngDataRange = Range("H9:H45000")

For Each rngCell In rngDataRange
    With rngCell
        If .Value < 0.03 Then
            .Offset(0, 1).Value = "0"    'A[rngCell] to C[rngCell]
        End If
    End With
Next rngCell
End Sub
```

**This is the macro I run first.... It puts values in some of the cells in column I (where column C has values less than 1575):**

Sub Macro1 ()
    Dim rngCell As Range,_
    rngDataRange As Range

```
Set rngdataRange = Range (C9:C45000)

For Each rngCell In rngDataRange
    With rngCell
        If .Value < 1575 Then
           .Offset (0,6).Value="1"
        End If
    End With
Next rngCell
```

End Sub

Comment: What have you tried so far? What's working/not working?

Comment: Can you edit your question and add your macro there?

Comment: Thanks for the guidance. Sorry for my ignorance.It should be edited... hopefully somewhat correctly

Comment: You mentioned that you are checking to see if there is a value of 1 in Column 'I', but I don't see that anywhere in your code. Are you doing that calculation somewhere else?

Comment: Is there a problem with the code? If it works as intended but it's slow, repetitive or otherwise inefficient, consider presenting your code on [codereview.se]; Stack Overflow is about *specific* programming issues... which I'm still not seeing in this post :(

Comment: Yes I run a separate macro to put values = 1 in Column I first.  Then I want to run these two (hopefully with one click) to check the rest.

Comment: One problem is that the second part locks excel up but yes I guess I'll go to a different site to try and find answers. Through my research I just ended up here like 3x so I thought I'd ask here.  Sorry to waste peoples time :(

Answer (score 2):

This should do the job.

```
Sub CheckClmI()

    Dim Rl As Long                      ' Last row
    Dim R As Long

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    With ActiveSheet
        ' Used range should be enough
        Rl = .UsedRange.Rows.Count

        For R = 9 To Rl
            If Val(.Cells(R, "I").Value) = 1 Then
                If Val(.Cells(R, "G").Value) < 30 Or _
                   Val(.Cells(R, "H").Value < 0.03) Then
                   .Cells(R, "I").Value = 0
                End If
            End If
        Next R
    End With
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: This looks like the way to go. I just didn't understand what was going on with the whole Column `I` part...

Comment: Thank you. However, when I run it, the macro fills column I with 0's even in instances where there was not a 1 to begin with and/or where columns G and H have values greater than (30 or 0.03)... not sure why this is though, to my untrained eye your answer looks good.

Comment: Seems like I need some language that says what to do if the IF statement is false... Like move the Next R line up before the End If ... though when I try to do that I get an error message and it won't let me try it :(

Comment: I did that bit latest last night and in a hurry. It contained a serious referencing error which occurred to me this morning before breakfast and that was the time I fixed it. Apologies! I also added `Val()` functions. They will ensure that numbers are processed even if they might be in Text format. I don't understand "move the next R line upd If". Please explain.

Comment: Your value of 45000 throws a question. Is there a column in your sheet which has a value in every used row from row 9 until the end? If you want to move rows this fact would be very useful.

Comment: I edited my original post to show the macro I run first.   It puts values of "1" in some of the rows in column I where column c < 1575 over the range I9:I45000                                Ignore my "Next R line" thing... I don't know what I'm talking about.                     When I run your newest macro it does not overwrite the 1's in column I when the conditions state it should.  I tried putting "1" in parentheses but that didn't work either.... sorry to be such a pain.

Comment: It looks like my attempt to gild the lily doesn't work. The Val() function produces a double, and doubles in Excel aren't always exactly what they seem. They may have a small value somewhere in the 6th digit to the right of the decimal point. So, 1 <> 1.000001. The easiest way you be for you to assign the number 1 to the cells in column I (not "1" as you have it), also make sure that you have numbers, not text, in G and H, and then remove the Val() functions from my code. The alternative would be to truncate the decimals produced by the Val() function.

Answer (score 0):

What about something like this?

```
Sub Macro1()
    OnError Goto OopsIDidItAgain
    Dim rngCell As Range, rngDataRange As Range

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set rngDataRange = Range("G9:G45000")

    For Each rngCell In rngDataRange
        With rngCell
            If .Value < 30 Or .Offset(0, 1).Value < 0.03 Then .Offset(0, 2).Value = "0"
        End With
    Next rngCell
OopsIDidItAgain:
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Since the range is large, I would turn off screenupdating before the start of the macro and re-activate it after the for loop

Comment: @TJYen, true true

Comment: Yes. I incorporated that in my answer as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can just do all the tests in one go:

```
Dim rngCell As Range
Dim rngDataRange As Range
Dim iCell as range
Dim hVal as variant

Set rngDataRange = Range("G9:G45000")
For Each rngCell In rngDataRange
    With rngCell
        Set iCell = .Offset (0,2)
        hVal = .Offset (0,1).Value

        If iVal = 0 or iVal = vbnullstring then
            If .Value < 30 or hVal > .3 Then
                iCell.Value = "0"    
            End If
        End if
    End With
 Next rngCell
 End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I like to count the rows so you don't have wasted loops.

```
Dim LstRw As Long
Dim Rng As Range, c As Range

LstRw = Cells(Rows.Count, "G").End(xlUp).Row
Set Rng = Range("G9:G" & LstRw)
For Each c In Rng.Cells
    If c < 30 Or c.Offset(, 1) < 0.03 Then c.Offset(, 2) = 0
Next c
```